# Using dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to define a function names Correct(), which has two parameters. A list of strings to be tested for misspelled words(this parameter will be my file), and my dictionary, which I have already made called mydictionary. 
The function should test each word in the first list using the dictionary and the check word() function. correct should return a list of words with all the misspelled words replaced. 
For example, correct([‘the’, ‘cheif’, ‘stopped’, ‘the’, ‘theif’]) should return the list [‘‘the’, ‘chief’, ‘stopped’, ‘the’, ‘thief’]
Then I'm supposed to test the function in the main()

```
import string
# Makes a function to read a file, use empty {} to create an empty dict
# then reads the file by using a for loop
def make_dict():
    file = open ("spellingWords.txt")
    dictionary = {}
    for line in file:
        # Splits the lines in the file as the keys and values, and assigning them as
# misspell and spell
        misspell, spell = string.split(line.strip())
        # Assigns the key to the value
        dictionary[misspell] = spell

    file.close()


    return dictionary

mydictionary = make_dict()



#print mydictionary

# Gets an input from the user
word = raw_input("Enter word")
# Uses the dictionary and the input as the parameters
def check_word(word,mydictionary):
    # Uses an if statement to check to see if the misspelled word is in the
    # dictionary
    if word in mydictionary:
        return mydictionary[word]
    # If it is not in the dictionary then it will return the word
    else:
        return word

# Prints the function
print check_word(word,mydictionary)

def main():
    file2 = open ("paragraph.txt")
    file2.read()
    thelist = string.split(file2)
    print thelist
    def correct(file2,mydictionary):
        return thelist
        paragraph = string.join(thelist)
        print paragraph

main()
```

All my other functions work besides my Correct() function and my Main() function. It is also giving me the error 'file object has no attribute split'. Can I get help with my mistakes?

so I corrected it and now have for my main function

```
def main():
    file2 = open ("paragraph.txt")
    lines = file2.read()
    thelist = string.split(lines)
    def correct(file2,mydictionary):
        while thelist in mydictionary:
            return mydictionary[thelist]
    paragraph = string.join(thelist)
    print correct(file2,mydictionary)
```

however I am now getting the error 'unhashable type: 'list''

Answer (score 1):

You are not understanding the concept of reading file object. You have to store the value that the method `read()` returns so that you can use it later.

`open` simply returns a file object, not the lines of a file. To read spy tuff, you can simply use methods to do things. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

To read the file:

```
lines = file.read()
# do something with lines - it's a super big string
```

Also, you don't have to import string, the `split()` method is already built in with strings.